# Parse out only specific text

Tags: bash, curl, awk, sed, grep

I have narrowed down my grepping to basically just the line which lists the CustName. This is from domaintools, basically grabbing the info using curl.

Here is an example of the output of the command:

```
grep -E -o "CustName.{120}" file
242:CustName:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Akamai&nbsp;Technologies<br/>Address:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbs
```

As you can see, the 120 just stands for characters after CustName which I think is a safe bet against other searches as well. The only information I want is Akamai Technologies. How can I parse out this data in the most efficient way up until the `<br/>`?

Note, this is just one domain, another domain might have more words so I cant use Awk and field separators here. Thank you for any help.

Comment: You are trying to get the "word" value between `CustName` and the first `<br/>`?

Comment: Also is `&nbspTechnologies` a typo or is there really a missing semi-colon there?

Comment: Hi. Yes Im trying to just return the value of CustName. Yes it was a typo sorry. I am using a VM and have no mouse integration. Had to type all of that.

Comment: You may not be fully aware of everything that awk is capable of. You never need grep and/or sed if you are using awk and there is nothing they can do that awk can't. If you post a few lines of sample input and expected output we could help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
sed 's/\(&nbsp;\)\+/ /g;s?<br/>.*??;s/^.*: //'
```

Answer (score 0):

On some quickly worked up example lines based on your example line the following seems to work:

```
sed -n '/CustName/{s/^.*CustName://;s/^\(&nbsp;\)\+//;s/\(&nbsp;\)\+/ /g;s/<br\/>.*$//p}'
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for grep:

```
$ cat file
foo
242:CustName:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Akamai&nbsp;Technologies<br/>Address:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbs
bar
242:CustName:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Some&nbsp;Other&nbsp;Company&nbsp;Name<br/>Address:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbs
whatever

$ awk -F': +|<' '/CustName:/{gsub(/&nbsp;/," "); print $2}' file
Akamai Technologies
Some Other Company Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another `awk` command:

```
awk -F: '$2 ~ /Cust/ { $0 = $3; gsub(/&nbsp;/, " ")
         gsub(/(^[ \t]+|[ \t]*<br.*$)/, ""); print }' file
```

Output:

```
Akamai Technologies
```

To have perfect matching use `==` instead:

```
awk -F: '$2 == "CustName" { $0 = $3; gsub(/&nbsp;/, " ")
         gsub(/(^[ \t]+|[ \t]*<br.*$)/, ""); print }' file
```

Or

```
awk -v name="CustName" -F: '$2 == name { $0 = $3; gsub(/&nbsp;/, " ")
                            gsub(/(^[ \t]+|[ \t]*<br.*$)/, ""); print }' file
```